# How can make an "iframe template page file" and force all links to open in that iframe page?

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, frame

I can make an iframe page (included my header and Iframe) But how to force links to open in that page?
(Setting a name for iframe and put it in target of links isn't enough)

I use WP platform (and Love it)

Thanks

Comment: Is there anyone to help me?

Comment: help me please....